# Is it possible to pivot in this way with pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe.

| report_id | landcover_type | data_type | mean | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 615 | Acid grassland | canopyheight | 2 | 493.9125 |
| 615 | Arable and horticulture | canopyheight | 4 | 0.86 |
| 615 | Acid grassland | carbonstoragewoodlands | 8 | 493.9125 |
| 615 | Arable and horticulture | carbonstoragewoodlands | 161 | 0.86 |

is it possible to pivot it so I have a new column for each distinct data_type with their own aggregation of my choosing like this?

| report_id | landcover_type | canopyheight_mean | carbonstorage_total | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 615 | Acid Grassland | 2 | 8 | 493.9125 |
| 615 | Arable and horticulture | 4 | 161 | 493.9125 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need change aggregate function by data - if numeric aggregate `mean` else aggregate join use:

```
print (df)
   report_id           landcover_type               data_type  mean area
0        615           Acid grassland            canopyheight     2   aa
1        615           Acid grassland            canopyheight     7   rr
2        615  Arable and horticulture            canopyheight     4   ss
3        615           Acid grassland  carbonstoragewoodlands     8   dd
4        615  Arable and horticulture  carbonstoragewoodlands   161   ff
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ','.join(x)
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['report_id', 'landcover_type'], 
                     columns= 'data_type',
                     aggfunc=f)

df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   report_id           landcover_type area_canopyheight  \
0        615           Acid grassland             aa,rr   
1        615  Arable and horticulture                ss   

  area_carbonstoragewoodlands  mean_canopyheight  mean_carbonstoragewoodlands  
0                          dd                4.5                          8.0  
1                          ff                4.0                        161.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and apply sum to a data_type that = 'something' and another one to a data_type that = something else?

Comment: @JamieDunbar - not understand, can you change data sample for it? Need some sample with expected ouput. Thanks.

Comment: @JamieDunbar - Added some solution, I hope it is what need.

Comment: I will give it a go! Thank you so much for your help.